# if(a%b) //what it means?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, c++14, implicit-conversion

```cpp
// take a=4 and b=2;

if(a%b)
  cout<<"true";
else
  cout<<"false";
```

The programs output `false`. I am a bit confused as the `if` condition passes only true values and `if(a%b`) means `a%b==0`; then why is it failing to pass the `if` statement?

Comment: In a verbose way, this is testing for if "a isn't perfectly divisible by b". As to how this works and what % does refer to the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Any expression that is not equal to 0 is converted to the logical true in the if statement.

Thus in this if statement

```
if(a%b)
```

the expression `a % b` (when a is equal to 4 and b is equal to 2) evaluates to 0. So the condition of the if statement is equal to false.

That
is the if statement is equivalent to

```
if( a%b != 0 )
```

The conditions

```
if(a%b)
```

and

```
if(a%b == 0 )
```

are two different conditions with the opposite meaning.

From the C++ 14 Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
> to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero
> value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
> to false; any other value is converted to true.** For
> direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
> converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition requires a boolean statement. a%b here becomes 0 (as 4 % 2 is equal to 0). In c/c++, 0 is considered false and non-zero is considered true. That is why, it is giving the result.

Answer (score 0):

`if(a%b)` does not mean `a%b==0`.

`a%b`, where `a` is 4 and `b` is 2, evaluates to `0`.

Thus, your `if` statement is `if(0)`, and `0` is interpreted as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

"%" is modulo operator (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-operator-in-c-cpp-with-examples/), 4%2==0 (https://www.calculators.org/math/modulo.php)

Comment: (4 % 2) evaluates to 0, not 2. Not sure if this is what you meant in your statement.

Comment: sorry, 4%2==0 and 4/2==2, the division have no remainder. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pV7DuzODik)